# Converting to and from bytes in java

Tags: java, byte

I am having trouble understanding converting to and from bytes, or bytes in general

```
byte b = (byte)170;
System.out.println("Byte to int" + (int)b);
```

why is it that when I cast 170 to a byte then cast that byte to an int I get -86 and what is the proper way to do this?

EDIT: Okay so the answer to my question was really simple (`byte` ranges from -128 to 127)... 
Where I was getting confused is that I really want is binary 10101010 to be in the byte so I figured represent that number in int and put that in the byte. Can someone please tell me how I can get that binary number into a byte?

Comment: You probably want to do `0xff&(int)b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binary representation of 170 as a  32-bit integer is

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1010 1010
```

When you cast that to a `byte`, it becomes `1010 1010`. Since all integers in Java are signed, it sees `1010 1010` as a [2's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) 8-bit integer. That's -86.

When you convert this byte back to integer using `(int) b`, it gets [signed extended](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension) to:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1010 1010
```

Which is also -86. You want to apply a bit mask to it, so it becomes 170 again.

`(int) (0xff & b)`  will give you 170 back:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1010 1010 
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111 & (bitwise and)
---------------------------------------
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1010 1010
```

Comment: Thank you for this very thorough explanation. I understand but just want to double check one thing. Is this the best way to represent 10101010 in a single byte? Int other words is there no way to represent this in java without using the bit mask?

Comment: @KevinMoore The bitmask lets **you** see the byte as an unsigned 8-bit int rather than a signed 8-bit int. As far as the machine is concerned, b is `10101010`. There's a difference between the data (`10101010`) and how you interpret it (-86 if you see it as signed int and 170 if you see it as an unsigned int)

Comment: Most comprehensive explanation ever!

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that byte is 8-bit data type and its range is from -128 to 127. So there is no "losless conversion"...

Comment: An unsigned 8-bit int can has a range from 0 to 255.

Comment: This is not relevant for Java, since there is no support for unsigned types.

Comment: Yes, there is no built-in support. That doesn't mean you can't work around that. You can have a method that translates a byte into an `int` (or `short`) assuming it's an unsigned 8-bit integer. Do the same going the other way. Now you have (somewhat hackish) support for unsigned 8-bit ints.

Comment: I don't know what the OP is trying to do with this, but I'm assuming they want to fit 170 in 8 bits for whatever reason. And that *can* be done.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ that is exactly what I am trying to do. please explain how to do this.

Comment: @KevinMoore See my answer for an explanation on why this is happening and a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The `byte` primitive type has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive).

You are trying to assign 170 (`int`) which is out of range of `byte` by explicit casting, which results in the loss of information about the overall magnitude of a numeric value.

See here: [Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Also check this JLS section: [5.1.3 Narrowing Primitive Conversions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/conversions.doc.html#25363)

Answer (score 1):

That's cause bytes are signed in java, so you're basically overflowing b.

Answer (score 1):

To convert integer number into a byte:

```
int original = 170;
byte b = (byte)(0xFF & original);
```

This will put 10101010 into the byteNum by "cutting off" anything outside the first byte.  If you print that number, you will get a -86. To convert back do this:

```
int num = (int)b & 0xFF;
```

This converts the byte into an integer, and then masks off the signature bit, restoring the value of 170.

Answer (score 0):

You cant store 170 into a byte. Byte size is from -128 to 127.

Comment: Yes, you can - make it unsigned.

Comment: An unsigned 8-bit int can has a range from 0 to 255. Problem is, there are no unsigned types in Java.

Comment: No, you cannot. Java does not support unsigned types…

Comment: Then the only solution is what i just said: assign it to short.http://darksleep.com/player/JavaAndUnsignedTypes.html

Comment: @MOleYArd I know that, but that's beyond the point. The question is essentially "can I fit 170 into 8 bits?" And the answer to that is "yes"

Comment: @NullUserException Java doesn't have unsigned data types, except for char.

Comment: @cosmic.osmo For the 100th time, I know that.